# Python Windows Installer with all dependencies?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, pypi

I have a package in the PyPI repository. I include a Windows installer by running the following command to upload a new version, specifically the 'bdist_wininst':

```
python3 setup.py register sdist bdist_wininst upload
```

However, when a user runs the associated .exe file, it does not install Python 3 itself. Furthermore, even if Python 3 is installed, it will not install any associated dependencies.

What is the best way to create a windows installer that will install Python 3 if it is not installed, along with my package and its dependencies?

If that is not possible, what is the best way to create a windows installer that will install my package and its dependencies, assuming Python 3 is installed?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. If it's of any assistance, here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

import codecs 
try: 
    codecs.lookup('mbcs') 
except LookupError: 
    ascii = codecs.lookup('ascii') 
    func = lambda name, enc=ascii: {True: enc}.get(name=='mbcs') 
    codecs.register(func) 

setup(
    name='SIGACTor',
    version='0.1.14dev',
    description=open('README.txt').read(),
    url='http://bitbucket.org/davidystephenson/sigactor',
    author='David Y. Stephenson',
    author_email='david@davidystephenson.com',
    packages=['sigactor'],
    license='Proprietary',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
        'beautifulsoup4',
        'feedparser',
        'python-dateutil',
        'pyyaml'
    ],
)
```

Comment: people should answer this only once: http://askubuntu.com/questions/315428/python-windows-installer-with-all-dependencies --- as askubuntu points people back to stackoverflow, maybe *this* question should becom the place where the question is answered :)

Comment: My apologies - I didn't understand the question would be migrated.

Comment: Are you wanting to make a Windows executable? Have you tried using `py2exe` or `PyInstaller` ? These packages would you to create an exe that allows a computer without Python already installed to run your program.

Comment: @Gator_Python I'm trying to create an installer for a python module.

Comment: @Daniel -- Isn't that the purpose of `pip` and PyPI? I just successfully downloaded and installed this package (and its dependencies) from PyPI on my Windows machine using `pip install sigactor` on Python3. `pip` ships with Python on Windows.

Comment: @Daniel It would help if you could explain what you need beyond the standard packaging tools.  For example, why are source distributions and [wheels](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/distributing/#wheels) no good for your use case?

Answer (score 6):

You should definetely try out pynsist which can bundle Python with your packages and is based on well-established NSIS open-source installer:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynsist

Anaconda team provides Constructor which is based on conda and NSIS again:

https://github.com/conda/constructor

Finally this approach using WinPython and most stable installer called InnoSetup:

http://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/

But if your package is not a library but an application then you can bundle it (freeze) with Python and all dependencies, even compress it using pyinstaller:

http://www.pyinstaller.org

This is what I use for all of my apps even with crazy interop dependencies!

Bonus - auto update tool for pyinstaller:

https://github.com/JMSwag/PyUpdater

Comment: +1 for pyinstaller.  +0 Didn't mention cython.  +0 Pyupdater, is the worlds most confusing updating system.  I've been trying to get it to update for 2 days... now.  I feel SAAS is the way to go and desktop apps are a dying art sadly.

Comment: I've had bad experience with tools that make their custom environments, especially run everything from a single file. They make it impossible to diagnose problems, and the unusual environment breaks common assumptions and the code that relies on them -- which is likewise impossible to diagnose. I.e. you can ship it but good luck supporting it.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev so what is your advice to shipping python apps?

Comment: The most natural option would be a GUI akin to bdist_wininst that would pip install a bunch of wheels. https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/redist_wininst.py.html looks like just the thing.

Comment: `This is what I use for all of my apps even with crazy interop dependencies!` - can you explain this or give some help or link ... I have pypi modules and binaries included and when runing pyinstaller with spec file and I start my exe it says no numpy ... So, no dependency is bundeled.

Comment: For pyinstaller you may need to create a virtualenv with just your dependencies and also provide a spec file with special includes or excludes according to the pyinstaller documentation.